# Understanding the connection between derivative and increasing of function at points

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm currently studying about derivatives, and i noticed this theorem:
"Let $f$ be a function defined in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Suppose that $f\:'\left(x_0\right)>0$. So $f$ is strictly increasing at $x_0$".

First, what does it even mean "$f$ strictly increasing at $x_0$"?
Second, can someone provide me a proof of that? I thought about the Mean Value Theorem but i don't know how to start, so maybe i need to use another approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly increasing means $$ x > y \Rightarrow f(x) > f(y)$$ for each $x$ and $y$ of the given domain, where the function shall increase strictly.

Your statement is not true. Take $$f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R : x \mapsto \begin{cases} \sin(x) & ; x \in \mathbb Q \\ x & ; x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \end{cases}$$ You have $f^\prime(0) = 1 > 0$, but $f$ is not strictly increasing in any neighborhood of $0$. You need, that $f$ is continuously differentiable with $f^\prime(x_0) > 0$...

So lets suppose, that $f$ is continuously differentiable. Then $f^\prime(x) > 0$ for any $x$ of a certain neighborhood of $x_0$. Fix $x$ and $y$ from this neighborhood with $x$ > $y$. From the mean value theorem you know $$f(x) = f(y) + f^\prime(c) (x-y)$$ whereby $c$ is a number in the interval $[y,x]$. Because $f^\prime(c)> 0$ you have $f(y) > f(x)$.

Comment: The assumption (though unstated) for this result is that $f$ is differentiable on its domain.

Comment: @tampis, the assumption "$f′(x)>0$ for any x of a certain neighborhood of x0." is not what i supplied. only for $x_0$ i know that $f'(x)>0$

Comment: @user2637293: When $f^\prime$ is continuous then it follows that $f^\prime$ is strictly positive in a neighborhood of $x_0$. The statement as you stated is not true (see my counterexample). Do you know that $f$ is differentiable or continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $x_0$?